# Snowflake stored procedure referencing tables from different databases

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My stored procedure resides in `DEV1` database. It is referencing a table `T1` from another database (`DEV2`).

I am getting the following error:

> SQL compilation error: database 'DEV2' does not exist or not authorized

Can I reference tables that reside in different databases? If so how can this issue be resolved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you hard coded the database name in your stored procedure?

Comment: Please share some barebones code trying to create this procedure

Comment: yes I had hard coded the database  . Something like this -   var sql_command = `Select Count(1) from  DATABASE.PUBLIC.TABLE   `  ;
  // Run the statement.
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
         {
         sqlText: sql_command
         }
      );
  var res = stmt.execute();
  
  res.next();

Comment: Did you define the SP execute as caller (default) or execute as owner? Does the caller have the USAGE grant on DEV2?

Comment: Yes using Execute as Caller helped. Thanks for your response.